# How to call a method from another method in the same .m file

Tags: objective-c, ios

Sorry for the complicated title but i'm not really sure the best way to word this, I have two methods here
.h

```
@interface Deck : NSObject

-(void) shuffle: (NSMutableArray *) unshuffledDeck;

-(NSMutableArray *) giveHand: (NSMutableArray *)  deck;

-(void) moveOpperand: (NSMutableArray *) moveFrom :(NSMutableArray *) moveTo;

@end
```

.m

```
-(void) moveOpperand: (NSMutableArray *) moveFrom :(NSMutableArray *) moveTo{
    NSString *opperandObject = [moveFrom lastObject];
    if (opperandObject) {
    [moveTo addObject:moveFrom.lastObject];
        [moveFrom removeLastObject];
    }
}

-(NSMutableArray *) giveHand: (NSMutableArray *)  deck{
    NSMutableArray *hand;
    for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
      [moveOpperand [_refrenceDeck] [hand]]; //use of undeclared identifier 'moveOpperand'
    }
    return hand;
}
```

and as you can see I am trying to call the one above in the one below, the issue is I keep getting the messages I commented above that says use of undeclared identifier, I have no idea why this is occurring so I was wondering, how do you call a method you wrote from another method in the same .m file?

Comment: Don't you want to read an Objective-C tutorial before writing an operating system in it?

Comment: `[self moveOperand:_referenceDeck :hand];` As declared the method is somewhat confusing - moveFrom is a parameter , not a parameter name, so [self moveOperand:_referenceDeck moveFrom:hand]; is wrong

Answer (score 2):

`[self moveOperand:_referenceDeck :hand];` As declared the method is somewhat confusing - moveFrom is a parameter , not a parameter name, so [self moveOperand:_referenceDeck moveFrom:hand]; is wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
[self moveOpperand:arg1 :arg2];
```

etc.

Also note that `self` refers to an instance / an actual object when in instance methods, and to the class itself when in class ("static") methods.

Comment: @JoshCaswell here you are -- it's hard to see behind this kind of terribly unreadable coding practice.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for the lesson in proper variable names! Its really nice to join a forum designed help answer coding questions only to be criticized about something you wernt asking about

Comment: @William: What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: @JoshCaswell  "it's hard to see behind this kind of terribly unreadable coding practice"

Comment: @William: Perhaps it could have been phrased more constructively, but your method _is_ poorly named, in that it has no label for the second parameter. It should be something like `-(void) moveOperandFrom: (NSMutableArray *)src to:(NSMutableArray *)dest`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell ah, that makes sense, I am still rather new to xcode and objective-c and didn't know there was a way to name the second variable